# if i want to add CSS where would i paste it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svn

here is the page where i need to add CSS:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg

since there is no body and header, where exactly would i paste the css?

here is what it looks like currently and it does not work?

```
somestyle.css
<style>
#tt {
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 background:url(images/tt_left.gif) top left no-repeat;
 }
 #tttop {
 display:block;
 height:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 background:url(images/tt_top.gif) top right no-repeat;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
 #ttcont {
 display:block;
 padding:2px 12px 3px 7px;
 margin-left:5px;
 background:#666;
 color:#fff;
 }
#ttbot {
display:block;
height:5px;
margin-left:5px;
background:url(images/tt_bottom.gif) top right no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.0"
   width="958.69"
   height="592.78998"
   id="svg2275"
   sodipodi:version="0.32"
   inkscape:version="0.46"
   sodipodi:docname="Map of USA with state names.svg"
   sodipodi:docbase="C:\temp\webdesign"
   inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape">


    <script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[

      function showRectArea(state) {
        var x = new Object();
        x["HI"] = "you clicked hawaii";
        x["CT"] = "you clicked CT";
        alert(x[state]);
      }

      var tooltip=function(){
      var id = 'tt';
 var top = 3;
 var left = 3;
 var maxw = 300;
 var speed = 10;
 var timer = 20;
 var endalpha = 95;
 var alpha = 0;
 var tt,t,c,b,h;
 var ie = document.all ? true : false;
 return{
  show:function(v,w){
   if(tt == null){
    tt = document.createElement('div');
    tt.setAttribute('id',id);
    t = document.createElement('div');
    t.setAttribute('id',id + 'top');
    c = document.createElement('div');
    c.setAttribute('id',id + 'cont');
    b = document.createElement('div');
    b.setAttribute('id',id + 'bot');
    tt.appendChild(t);
    tt.appendChild(c);
    tt.appendChild(b);
    document.body.appendChild(tt);
    tt.style.opacity = 0;
    tt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
    document.onmousemove = this.pos;
   }
   tt.style.display = 'block';
   c.innerHTML = v;
   tt.style.width = w ? w + 'px' : 'auto';
   if(!w && ie){
    t.style.display = 'none';
    b.style.display = 'none';
    tt.style.width = tt.offsetWidth;
    t.style.display = 'block';
    b.style.display = 'block';
   }
  if(tt.offsetWidth > maxw){tt.style.width = maxw + 'px'}
  h = parseInt(tt.offsetHeight) + top;
  clearInterval(tt.timer);
  tt.timer = setInterval(function(){tooltip.fade(1)},timer);
  },
  pos:function(e){
   var u = ie ? event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop : e.pageY;
   var l = ie ? event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft : e.pageX;
   tt.style.top = (u - h) + 'px';
   tt.style.left = (l + left) + 'px';
  },
  fade:function(d){
   var a = alpha;
   if((a != endalpha && d == 1) || (a != 0 && d == -1)){
    var i = speed;
   if(endalpha - a < speed && d == 1){
    i = endalpha - a;
   }else if(alpha < speed && d == -1){
     i = a;
   }
   alpha = a + (i * d);
   tt.style.opacity = alpha * .01;
   tt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + alpha + ')';
  }else{
    clearInterval(tt.timer);
     if(d == -1){tt.style.display = 'none'}
  }
 },
 hide:function(){
  clearInterval(tt.timer);
   tt.timer = setInterval(function(){tooltip.fade(-1)},timer);
  }
 };
}();


    ]]>
  </script>


  <metadata
     id="metadata2625">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs2623">
    <inkscape:perspective
       sodipodi:type="inkscape:persp3d"
       inkscape:vp_x="0 : 296.39499 : 1"
       inkscape:vp_y="0 : 1000 : 0"
       inkscape:vp_z="958.69 : 296.39499 : 1"
       inkscape:persp3d-origin="479.345 : 197.59666 : 1"
       id="perspective364" />




  </defs>
```

the css for some reason is not working.

i know the javascript is working because i put an alert which pops up. but the CSS is being ignored completely.

Comment: Ask enough and eventually you'll get some badges!  The SO carpet bomb approach.

Comment: i am happy to give any one of you all of my points. i dont care about any badges. i need to learn so i ask questions. you would probably learn more if you werent so timid

Comment: @!__ - It is more a question of "what is the correct question" and "in context of all your other questions" I see WHAT you are trying to do, now how best to guide you to a satifactory result...regarding the .svg thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html

**UPDATE**

```
mystyle.css
rect {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 3
}

SVG file referencing mystyle.css
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="10cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <rect x="200" y="100" width="600" height="300"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: alex, thank you very much for your help. unfortunately i am not able to get this working

Comment: i actually dont think that i need it inside the svg, i just need it outside, where would i stick it outside?

Comment: alex thank you again, ive done what you said, but it seems like the CSS is being ignored. i know that the javascript is working because i am succesfully returning an ALERT from the function